# How to make UISlider have discrete intervals? For example intervals of 5000

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

How do I round or make intervals of 5000 on a ui slider in swift?

```
@IBAction func incomeSliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var incomeValue = Double(sender.value)
    currentIncomeLabel.text = ("$\(incomeValue) /yr")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following code. You can also make the slider discrete using the 3rd line(with comment).

```
@IBAction func incomeSliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    var interval = 5000
    var incomeValue = Int(sender.value / Float(interval) ) * interval
    sender.value = Float(incomeValue) // remove this if you don't want discrete slider.
    currentIncomeLabel.text = ("$\(incomeValue) /yr")
}
```

Comment: This works for Integer intervals, but does it work if the interval is a Float?

Comment: no. this is specifically for integer intervals. will have to modify the code for float intervals.